Как двигать объект вслед за анимацией его дочернего объекта Unity 3D
У меня есть 2 объекта, один - дочерний другого. На главном объекте висит анимация, которая изменяет позицию дочернего, но после окончания анимации он не дожен возвращаться в начальную точку. Как сделать так, чтобы по окончанию анимации и дочерний и главный объекты были в одной точке, то есть перенести главный к дочернему?

Можно использовать DoTween и там уже передавать нужную позицию смещения.
public class BoxController : MonoBehaviour
{
     [SerializeField] private GameObject _children;

     void Start()
     {
         _children.transform.DOMove(Vector3.forward, 1);
         //Первый аргумент указывает направление(Можно указать transform другого объекта.).
         //Второй аргумент указывает время выполнения в секундах.
     }
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
